# AS3: Add A Text Field To a Movie Clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield, movieclip

How do you go about adding a text field to a movie clip? Then add the text to the text field through your main actions. Also how would you reset that back to nothing for example " ".

Comment: Have you tried creating a TextField object ? If so, you can add it to a movieclip using `addChild` like you would any other DisplayObject(e.g. Sprite,MovieClip). The TextField object has a `.text` property which is a String, so you can set the text(something or nothing "" like you mention). Sounds to me you haven't had a look at the [documentation and examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#includeExamplesSummary) do that first and if you still can't figure it out, show what you've attempted and the rest will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example ...

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;

var textField:TextField = new TextField();
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

addChild(container).addChild(textField);

function get text():String {
  return textField.text;
}

function set text(value:String):void {
  textField.text = value;
}

function resetTextField():void {
  text = "";
}
```

In your MovieClip, which contains the script:

```
movieClip.text = "Fred";
```

Comment: For example, yes. The code is not tested but should compile.

Comment: I'm sorry this text field stuff is new to me but how to I send the value to it from my main action script to the movie clip

Comment: Check my edit. Although the container is basically obsolete, since I didn't fully understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

An Easy way to do this is if you take the text tool draw a box where you want the text to appear, then turn that text box to dynamic text. Then give it an instance name, from there in your code you'll be able to use an array to push the text you want to the box depending on what the user clicked.

Also you can edit the text size and color and font very easily this way.